# Extracting data from XML in Erlang

Tags: xml, erlang, ejabberd

I have this XML:

```
<message from="adminhash@localhost/xmpphp2" to="queue@springfruitdev"
type="service" id="service1"><body>JSON</body></message>
```

I want to extract text between  tags.

Here's how it's been represented in erlang:

`{xmlel,<<"message">>,
        [{<<"xml:lang">>,<<>>},
         {<<"from">>,<<"adminhash@localhost/xmpphp2">>},
         {<<"to">>,<<"queue@springfruitdev">>},
         {<<"type">>,<<"service">>},
         {<<"id">>,<<"service1">>}],
        [{xmlel,<<"body">>,[],[{xmlcdata,<<"JSON">>}]}]}}`

What i've tried by pattern matching:

```
element(1,list_to_tuple(element(4,element(3,X)))).
```

Result:

```
{xmlel,<<"body">>,[],[{xmlcdata,<<"JSON">>}]}
```

First of all, can i extract xmlcdata in more elegant way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use some of the functions in `xml.erl`:

```
> xml:get_tag_cdata(xml:get_subtag(X, <<"body">>)).
<<"JSON">>
```

That is, get the `body` child element, and then get all character data from it.

Answer (score 7):

Another option in xml.erl is the function

> xml:get_path_s/2

**TL;DR;**

to get body cdata you would use the following

```
>xml:get_path_s(El,[{elem,"body"},cdata]).
"JSON"
```

**MORE DATA**

You provide the Xml has the first argument, and the second argument is list with the following sintax,

- {elem,StringWithTagName} - a subtag of El
- {attr, StringWithAtributeName} - a atribute of El
- cdata - the cdata of El

I will provide the following examples for better understanding.
Imagine that your xml is the following

```
<message from="adminhash@localhost/xmpphp2" to="queue@springfruitdev"
type="service" id="service1">
   <body>JSON</body>
   <writer id="123">
     <name>William</name>
     <country>England</country>
   </writer>
</message>
```

You have the following invocations and results.

```
>xml:get_path_s(El,[{elem,"body"},cdata]).
"JSON"

>xml:get_path_s(El,[{elem,"body"}]).
{xmlel,"body",[],[{xmlcdata,<<"JSON">>}]}

>xml:get_path_s(El,[{attr,"type"}]).
"service"

>xml:get_path_s(El,[{elem,"writer"},{elem,"name"},cdata]).
"William"

>xml:get_path_s(El,[{elem,"writer"},{attr,"id"}]).
"123"
```

Comment: Nuno Freitas, I don't know if this is specific from ejabberd, but in your third example just works for me when a change:

"{elem,"writer"}" and "{elem,"name"}"

to:
"{elem,list_to_binary("writer")}" and "{elem,list_to_binary("name")}"

Thanks!

Comment: I wrote the question using my experience in ejabberd 2.1.X (and just a little bit of 13.X).
if your xml representation structure is similar to what the OP posted it makes completely sense.
The way ejabberd now structures xml may have changed to what I was used to.
Sorry if my answer is a bit outdated.

Comment: Yes, but your answer was helped me a lot. Thanks again! :)

Comment: Does it work with the new xml ejabberd package fxml?